# rails oauth and using FB mobile app if we are mobile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, omniauth

I am using the facebook omniauth gem and would like to solve the following simple problem:

In case a user browses my rails app mobile (e.g. via iPhone, iPad) I would like him to authenticate via his FB app on his device. Currently the auth happens via the browser version of Facebook which is a weird user experience.

I was looking into the configuring parameters via https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook but could not find any help there.

I assume I need to edit my omniauth.rb file which currently looks like this:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
     provider :facebook, 'XXXXXXX', 'XXXXXX',
     :scope => 'email'
  end
```

Thanks

Comment: How is your mobile app implemented ? Is it a native Obj-C/Cocoa app or a web app on a thin native layer ?

Comment: Hi. Sorry if this is not clear but I'm talking of my rails app that is viewed mobile.

Comment: Are you using something like PhoneGap or is your application accessed through the browser ?

Comment: Through the Browser only

Comment: So basically you want to authenticate your web app via facebook mobile   application right.Is it correct?

Comment: correct. only if the user is mobile obviously.

Comment: I am looking into the same problem. Did you solve it in the end? I basically ant to pass face uid and accesstoken and whatever else is needed to my rails app and the login like i would using the webapp.

Answer (score 0):

You should use 'omniauth-facebook' and 'devise' gem. It's simple.

More information: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview

Example link: https://github.com/mohitjain/social-login-in-rails

Hope can help you.

Comment: I won't use devise as I built my own auth system. I also cannot see how devise would solve the problem.